# Sending data between mobile devices in a physical range of 100 meters

Tags: android, ios, networking, mobile, windows-phone-8

I'm coding a game of sorts, and I'd like to be able to let people play locally with people in the same geographic area. Like a room, bus, park, whatever. I would probably be using android for this, though I'm open to other devices if they're a better fit.

All I've been able to come up with so far is a model with some kind of central server that groups people based on co ords from mobile phone's gps. But this would require data and a connection to cell towers and all that, plus it would introduce a fair bit more lag.

I was also considering some kind of ad hoc wireless network where a device tries to connect to a host, and if none is found, makes itself a host. I don't know that that particular route would work though, I looked into something like that for android, and it seems to have a very limited range.

I'd love some input from someone more knowledgeable than I on the subject.

Comment: If your lucky, the Google Services component for gaming that was released at Google I/O in the past hour will also have services for local gaming capabilities; which would of course make something along handling connectivity like this a matter of using the correct API.

Comment: I just saw that as well, but it's not going to be released for a while at least, it's still in development.